# Photoshop Script to export all layers to files for all open documents

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I need to create a Photoshop Script that exports all layers to files for all open documents.
The feature for the current active document is very useful, but what if I need to do that for all open files with one click? Unfortunately, I have no JavaScript or Photoshop Scripting experience, so I don't know how to start.

Ideally the script would per open document:

1. Export all visible layers to files (TIF format with LZW compression)
2. Delete all layers that start with "Layer XY"
3. Make all other layers visible again
4. Save and close the file.

Alternatively:

1. Export all layers starting with "Layer ...XY" to files (TIF format with LZW compression)
2. Delete these layers
3. Make sure all other layers are visible
4. Save and close the file

The filename should be **"Original Filename" + " - Layername"**

Anyone who can help me with that? Thanks a lot in advance!

The  Photoshop version in question is Photoshop 2020 (v21)

Comment: You start by reading [guides and references](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html). With what part do you need help exactly? Currently you question looks more like a job description

Comment: I would love to do that, just at the moment I could hardly find the time to get into JavaScript. Unfortunately, I'd need such a script rather urgently, so, yes, if someone could help me out here, I would greatly appreciate that. I do know Python sufficiently to imagine that this can't be too difficult.

Comment: In this case you should probably hire someone. It's not  too difficult but helping by answering a question and writing a whole script for you isn't the same thing.